# How to update a mapbox feature coordinate periodically

Tags: angular, mapbox

I am rendering approximately 100k features on the map using geojson file. When user zoom into a certain level, I would like to periodically pull the data from DB to update the feature coordinates on the viewport.

```
setInterval(()=> {
    console.log(this.map.getZoom());
    if(this.map.getZoom() >= 12) {
      // Get viewport features
      const list = this.map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['datalayer'] });
      console.log(list);
      // list.forEach(fea => {
      //how to update the feature coordinates???

      .... 
      // })
    }
  }, 10000);

});
```

I did some research I found the setFeatureState but this can only update the properties value instead of coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFeatureState` can change properties and you can use that for hover or some changing in properties.

`queryRenderedFeatures` get features that already rendered.
mapbox first convert geojson to tiles and then show the map so if you use `queryRenderedFeatures` it gets only rendered features for each tile. so you have rendered fetures with duplicate properties and unique coordinates.

you can use `this.map.getSource('some id').serialize().data` to get all of your data and make a loop on features and after some changing on geometry in your hole data you can set your new data with `this.map.getSource('some id').setData(new_data)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your recommendation, how about if the data source is in json file instead? I using the getSource().serialize().data return me the URL of json